# Java swing CheckBox is not visible in JCheckBoxMenuItem

Tags: swing

The checkbox icon is not visible in my JCheckBoxMenuItem..I add this JCheckBoxMenuItem to JideMenu which extends JMenu.How to make this checkbox visible eventhough if it is not selected..?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain where your problem is coming from.  It sounds that just the checkbox component isn't visible, while all other MenuItem types are showing up on the Menu.

I'm not very experienced with the Swing library, but if you could put a few lines of code regarding your Menu/MenuItems, I'm certain you'll get a much better answer.

Taking a shot in the dark, you mention that the MenuItem (checkbox) is added to the menu, but have you added the menu into a MenuBar/JMenuBar object and set your JFrame to use that Bar via the setMenuBar() method?  This is under the assumption that the entire menu isn't showing up (not just the checkbox component), but figured I'm try to preempt a solution here.

Answer (score 0):

```
menuBar = new JMenuBar();
menu = new JMenu("A Menu");
menuBar.add(menu);
cbMenuItem = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("A check box menu item");
menu.add(cbMenuItem);
```

It´s pretty much straightforward and taken directly from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html). I guess it´s all anyone can say about it until you show us your code.

Comment: You'll need to add cbMenuItem.setState(true) to make the checkmark visible.

Answer (score 0):

setState(true) will show the checkmark… IIRC there's also a constructor that you can pass a boolean if you want it created with the checkmark visible.